# Why does an HTML <a> tag inside a section/div produce a duplicate outside of the section/div?

Tags: html, anchor, markup

I've been trying to make a scroller for a website with some arrows on the side, but the arrows are going crazy and duplicating themselves in following sections.  I've simplified the problem to the below - when I put one a-tag inside a section, where the a-tag is a colored shape thanks to some CSS, it produces a duplicate after the section ends.  Here is some code below to try out:

```
<head>
<style>
a#block { height:30px; width:30px; display:block; background:blue; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <a id="block"/>
    </section>
</body>
```

I realise that the above looks like terrible use of mark up, but it's for a reason.  The block is a simplification of an action arrow (hence the  tag), and the section is necessary as there will be more inside of it.

I have no idea why this is happening, I never thought that HTML elements could duplicate.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<a id="block"/>` is not valid HTML. `<a>` must have a closing tag: `<a id="block"></a>`.

Always [validate your code](http://validator.w3.org/check) when you get odd errors. It can be very enlightening.

Comment: Spot on.  I'm using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 express, it tends to mark any errors in green and it didn't, so I figured my code was fine.  But I just tried building it then (which I'll admint I haven't been doing), it does throw the green error marks.  I don't get why <a> needs a closing tag and almost everything else (inc. section, div) don't.  Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: There's a section in the HTML5 spec about [types of elements](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#elements-0). `a` is a *normal element*, which (usually) must have both a start and end tag. There are some weird exceptions, it's worth a quick read.